# Boto3/Lambda - Join multiple outputs from a loop and send in one email using AWS SNS

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

New to Python/Boto3, this should be an easy one but still learning :)

I have a Lambda function which creates a number of snapshots and works fine:

```
def create_snapshot():
    volumes = ec2_client.describe_volumes(
        Filters=[
            {'N'...
    ...
    for volume in volumes...
        ....
        snap_name = 'Backup of ' + snap_desc
        ....
        snap = ec2_client.create_snapshot(
            VolumeId=vol_id,
            Description=snap_desc
        )
```

I then want to receive an email from AWS SNS to let me know which snapshots the function created, which I do using:

```
message = sns.publish(
    TopicArn=SNSARN,
    Subject=("Function executed"),
    Message=("%s created" % snap_name)
)
```

The issue is that this creates an email for each snapshot, instead of one email listing all the snapshots. Should I create another function that calls all values produced by snap_desc, or can I send all values for snap_desc in the function? And most importantly what's the best way of doing this?

Cheers!

Scott

```
####################### UPDATE (Thanks @omuthu) #######################
```

I set an array inside and outside the loop, and put the string into the message. This produced the following being sent in one message:

The following snapshots have been created:
['vol-0e0b9a5dfb8379fc0 (Instance 1 - /dev/sda1)', 'vol-03aac6b65df64661e (Instance 4 - /dev/sda1)', 'vol-0fdde765dfg452631 (Instance 2 - /dev/sda1)', 'vol-0693a9568b11f625f (Instance 3 - /dev/sda1)', etc.

Comment: Code looks good. Is the sns code part of the loop? Or does the lambda gets triggered by any event? If it is  a scheduled trigger, definitely the publish sns is part of the loop causing one email per snapshot.

Comment: SNS is part of the loop, and getting triggered for every snapshot that the python function creates. Sorry I also have this line after SNS: print("Response: {}".format(message)) I'd like to move it out of the loop, but trying to figure out how to call snap_desc to provide all the different outputs for each loop and send to SNS in one message is where I'm stuck.

Comment: ok I assume, the value of snap_desc is getting set in each iteration of the loop. So, have an array outside of the loop and append the snap_desc to the array and finally while sending sns, convert array to string for "Message" #Outside loop snap_desc_arrary = []; #Inside loop snap_desc_array.append(snap_desc) #In sns message, str(snap_desc_arr)

Comment: Thanks @omuthu. I tried arrays any they worked, however the output was one long output. I did the same using _list and am very nearly there! I updated the question above with the new info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it sorted, finally!

```
def create_snapshot():

    volumes = ec2_client.describe_volumes(
        Filters=[
            {'N'...
    ...

    inst_list = []

    for volume in volumes...
        vol_id = volume['VolumeId']
        ....
        snap_desc = vol_id
        for name in volume['Tags']:
            tag_key = name['Key']
            tag_val = name['Value']
            if tag_key == 'Name':
                snap_desc = vol_id + ' (' + tag_val + ')'
                ....
                ....
                ....

        if backup_mod is False or (current_hour + 10) % backup_mod != 0:
            ...
            continue

        else:
            print("%s is scheduled this hour" % vol_id)

            for name in volume['Tags']:
                inst_tag_key = name['Key']
                inst_tag_val = name['Value']
                if inst_tag_key == 'Name':
                    inst_list.append(inst_tag_val)

        snap = ec2_client.create_snapshot(
            VolumeId=vol_id,
            Description=snap_desc,
        )

        print("%s created" % snap['SnapshotId'])

    msg = str("\n".join(inst_list))

    if len(inst_list) != 0:
        message = sns.publish(
            TopicArn=SNSARN,
            Subject=("Daily Lambda snapshot function complete"),
            Message=("The following snapshots have been created today:\n\n" + msg + "\n")
        )

        print("Response: {}".format(message))
```